# How do I find elements in array with another indexes array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

I have two arrays:

`["mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"]` and `[1, 5]`

What is the shortest, most clean way to make a new array from the first array, based on the indexes of the second array?
I would like to do something like this:

`["mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"][[1, 5]]` (not possible this way)

This would yield `["tu", "sa"]`.

How could this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this as below using [**Array#values_at**](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#values_at-instance_method)

```
a = ["mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"] 
b= [1, 5]
c = a.values_at(*b) 
# => ["tu", "sa"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`select` and `with_index` can be chained to pluck certain elements from an array:

```
["mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"].select.with_index {|_, index| [1, 5].include?(index)}
# => ["tu", "sa"]
```

Here's a couple of notes on this answer for Ruby newbies:

1. The first block variable represents the days of the week ("mo", "tu", etc.) and is not used, but the convention is to name the variable "_"
2. The `with_index` method can be chained with any of the awesome Ruby iterators to gain access to the index (similar to `each_with_index`).  In this case, there is no `select_with_index`, so we use `select.with_index`.